# conditionally wrap <td> data in a link with vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to look at a certain table cell `td` element and set a condition, so that if the condition is met I show the data in a link, and if not I just show the data as text

I can't seem to figure out how to make this happen. I currently have a hover over that is set to that link and I've set the condition on my anchor tag but it's not working at all.

I have a snippet below, but basically I expect to see 0 printed as a link that triggers the hover/popover functionality. If test is set to 1, I would expect to just see a printed 1

Where am i wrong here?

```js
<script>
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  props: { 
    text: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data: {
    timeout: null,
    showCard: false,
    isLoaded: false,
    selected: '',
    test: 0
  },
  methods: {

    mouseover: function (event) {
      console.log(event.pageX, event.pageY)
      clearTimeout(this.timeout)
      var self = this
      this.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
         self.showCard = true
         setTimeout(function () {
           self.isLoaded=true;
         }, 500)
      }, 500)
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
      var self = this
      this.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        self.showCard = false
        self.isLoaded = false
      }, 200)
    },
    cardOver: function () {
      console.log('card over')
      clearTimeout(this.timeout);
      this.showCard = true
    },
    cardLeave: function () {
      var self = this
      this.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        self.showCard = false
        self.isLoaded = false
      }, 200)
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<table id="app">
<tbody>
<td>
  <a v-if="test == 0" href="javascript:void(0)" 
         @mouseover="mouseover"
         @mouseleave="mouseleave">@{{test}}
            </a>
           <div id="hovercard" v-show="showCard" @mouseover="cardOver" @mouseleave="cardLeave">
      <div :class="['bg', {'loaded': isLoaded}]"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Orders ready</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `var self = this` eww

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered

```
<a v-if="test == 0"
  href="javascript:void(0)" 
  @mouseover="mouseover"
  @mouseleave="mouseleave">{{test}}
</a>
<span v-else>{{test}}</span>
```

Docs: [Conditional rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your anchor inside in-built `component` tag conditionally. below is the sample snippet.

```html
<td>
  <component :is="test == 0 ? 'a' : 'span'" @mouseover="mouseover" @mouseleave="mouseleave" :href="'javascript:void(0)' || ''" target="_blank">{{ test }}</component>
</td>
```